# Чи вважається слово добавка питомим українським?

Tags: вживання-слів, from-russian, віддієслівні-іменники

Чи вважається слово *"добавляти"* та *"добавка"* запозиченням з російської?

СУМ потверджує, що слово *добавка* з позначкою розмовне має такі значення:

- Те саме, що добавляння. (дія)
- Те, що є доповненням до чого-небудь. (річ)
- Додаткова порція їжі.

Слово *додача* має такі значення:

- Дія за значенням додавати
- Те, що додається.

Слово *додаток* має такі значення:

- рідко. Дія за значенням додавати
- Те, що додається, служить доповненням до чого-небудь.

Чи можуть слова додача або додаток цілковито замінити слово добавка? Адже у фразі "просити добавки" слова додача або додаток звучать незвично: просити додачі або просити додатку

Answer (score 3):

Всі проблеми зі статусом слова "добавка" є пов'язані з такими проблемами:

1. Насамперед в українській порівняльний лінгвістиці, дуже часто вживається поняття "однокореневий". Тоді, як у західній лінгвістиці частіше вживається слово "cognate" - "споріднений", "родич" для визначення спільної міжмовної лексики. І не для всіх лінгвістів достатньо "одного" (спільного) кореня для того щоб 2 назвали  "спорідненими". Існують жорсткі вимоги там (помічені радянськими лінгвістами М.Араповим і М.Херц в книжці "Математические методы в лингвистике", сторінки,26, 57-59 і висунуті угорським лінгвістом Іштваном Федором в 1960- х рр., західними лінгвістами R.L.Trusk, I. Dien, K.Peust, J. Mattice - List. Частково ці підходи є й в "Етимологічному словнику української мови". Також вони фактично присутні й частково пояснються в публікації відомого українського лінгвіста К.Тищенка "Правда про походження української мови", особливо на сторінці 54, де неспоріднена лексика є забарвленою як "іновації" у фрагменті списку Сводеша (а також на 53 і 55 сторінках, [слайд 34](https://archive.org/details/tishenko/mode/1up)).

Слід сказати, що не є відомо, чи завжди доцільно вживати слово "спільний корінь" а не "близький корінь". НаприкладБ згідно з "Етимологічним словником слов'янських мов російське слово "дитя" (повний родич українському дитя за умови повної однаковості значення) а також українське "дитина" разом походять від спільної гіпотетичної праслов'янської основи *detb (сторінки 12-14). Однак, "дитя" прямо походить від *dete (с.12-13) а "дитина" (якщо це слово ще дійсно повністю співпадає по значенню зі словом "дитя", бо може означати в російській тільки " мала дитина") прямо походить від інших праслов'янських слів-коренів - *detim>(jb)/ *detina(ja) / *detino (с.14 -15) - https://imwerden.de/pdf/etimologichesky_slovar_slavyanskikh_yazykov_vyp05_1978__ocr.pdf  Отже,логічно, корінь тут не "один" (спільний), а просто "близький". Подібна ситуація з парами "писатель- письменник","свет- світло".
Отже, вимогами для споріднених слів є (окрім уявного спільного кореню):

А) Однакове значення слова (Згідно з визначним американським лінгвістом Icidore Dyen, лексикостатистика (підрахунок спільної лексики наприклад у Списку Сводеша) повинна базуватися на визнанні підрахунку тих слів, які мають однакове значення, про що сказано у його [публікації](https://thevore.com/comparative-indoeuropean-database-collected-by-isidore-dyen/), у розділі під назвою "The history of the data in this file".

При чому має бути повністю спільне значення, а не там "дуже близьке, що підкреслено наприклад, російськими лінгвістами О.Касіяном й А.Дибо в в їхній додатковій інформації (supplementary informftion) 2 до публікації  "Genetic heritage of the Balto-Slavic speaking populations: a synthesis of autosomal, mithochondrial and Y-chromosomal data (Alena Kushniarevich et al.).

Б) Спільна успадкованість слів від мови - предка (гіпотетичної давньосхіднослов'янської (давньоруської) але частіше - від праслов'янської) а не "запозичення" (borrowings) принаймні з двох різних "третіх мов".
Слід зауважити, що K.Peust й I.Dyen вважали неспорідненими слова між мовами навіть запозичені одна від одної. Зокрема, за I.Dyen англійське blossom є родичем французькому fleur але не англійське flower. Навіть без історичних відомостей про запозичення, останнє буде видно через відсутність "регулярних звукових відповідностей" Про це він написав у одній із своїх лексикостатичних книг [Indo-European languages](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=AoGmexxHvJQC&pg=PA81&dq=Indo-European+languages+isidore+Dyen&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI5LjWsbb8AhVri8MKHUBrADAQ6wF6BAgGEAU#v=onepage&q=Indo-European+languages+isidore+Dyen&f=false) на сторінці 95.

В) "Пряме" походження від конкретного слова-предка з мови-предка (ось ця проблема пов'язана зі словами "дитя - дитина", "свет-світло", тощо).

Проблеми, очевидно, не буде, якщо відбулося "непряме походження " вже не у мові-предку, а у пізніших мовах, але щоб була:

Г.) Так звана "регулярна" відповідність звуків і "регулярні" (відносно часті і згідно з "природним" процесом зміни звуків при розділенні мов) зміни звуків. Прикладом регулярної зміни звуків є наявність "і" в закритому складі в українській мові там де в російській мові є "о" (пара "вол - віл"). Особливо "важливо" щоб "регулярні зміни були в коренях.
Про вплив на спорідненість "розходження" у коренях писав зокрема І.Фодор у своїй [публікації](http://www.lllf.uam.es/%7Eclase/acceso_local/IF61Gloto.pdf) (с. 321.) на прикладі коренів `*mazъ` - `mast`. Він писав там і про інші ознаки споріднених, хоч його підхід і підрахунок Списку Сводеша мав проблемні місця посічені деякими вченими.

Лінгвіст Kirschen Peust (Німеччина) писав про важливість негативного впливу навіть нерегулярних суфіксів та префіксів, однак, вважав, що слово може вважатися спорідненим, якщо споріднена частина разом з коренем буде достатньо великою (Сторінка 2-3 файлу [публікації](http://www.peust.de/peustBasicVocabularyList.pdf), там де є пункт "Сognate judgement", а також - застосування правил у фрагменті списку Сводеша починаючи зі стор.5).

Отже, [згідно](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8#2966) з Етимологічним словником української мови в 7 томах, (("добавка" є словотвірним варіантом слова "вибавити"**. Це діалектичне слово є напівспоріднене з російським "избавить" маючи принаймні частково (в певних випадках застосування). однакове значення. Однак, на відміну від зміни звуку "ть" на звуки "ти", у закінченні (регулярна звукова зміна), заміна "із" на "ви"  - нерегулярна).
Але ця заміна є не в корені (він є спорідненим і походить від віддаленого і часткового праслов'янського предка українського слова "бути" https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8 У самрму слові "бути" якому є "нерегулярні" звукові зміни в староукраїнськму "бити" під впливом майбутньої форми "буду", а в "чужих" між собою "префіксах". Тому можна ще назвати ці два слова "спільною" лексикою.
Позаяк, непряме походження російського "добавка" (від "ИЗбавить" і українського "добавка" (від "ВИбавити" сталося не в час існування праслов'янської мови, а пізніше, то ці 2 слова "добавка" є "родичами" "спорідненими". У них також немає "нерегулярних" звукових змін як от між рос. "прыгать" і укр. "плигати" ,або у "ладонь - "долоня", "он-він". В письмовій формі вони взагалі однакові.

2. Часто у подібних питааннях існує проблема різниці між стандартними (літературними) мовами і їхніми нестандартними варіантами, як от архаїзми чи діалектизми. Стандартні є більше подібними чи різними в одних словах чи коренях, а нестандартні  - в інших. Часто буває, що в одній стандартній мові рідше застосовується якийсь корінь ніж в іншій літературній мові. А от в нестандартний. Буває й протилежна ситуація.

До прикладів більшого застосування спільних чи близьких іншої літературної мови коренів у "нелітературній" мові є український діалектизм "глитати" споріднений з російським літературним "глотать". Зараз, в українській мові застосовується контакти. Але близькі до "глотать" корені застосовуються у словах вже чужої цьому російському слові літературній лексиці - укр. "глитай"  (має неоднакове значення), "поглинати"(до неожнакового значення ще й "нерегулярні" звукові зміни саме в коренях додалися).

Comment: Вітаю на цьому сайті і вітаю з дуже якісними першими дописами! Думаю, що найближчим часом ваші дописи отримають достатньо «плюсів» upvotes. І як тільки це станеться, ви зможете додавати у ваші дописи достатню кількість гіперпосилань (певен, ви маєте ці посилання).

Comment: Невеличке виправлення щодо «а від іншого, праслов'янського слова "*первший"»: наскільки я розумію, _*первший_ — не праслов'янське, а (зникле нині й реконструйоване етимологами) українське слово.

Answer (score 0):

Існує кілька слів з закінченням *бавка* з різними префіксами, наприклад:

- [надбавка](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- [добавка](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- [прибавка](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Лише *прибавка* не є позначеною як розмовне. Беручи до уваги факт, що слово *бавка* саме по собі не має ніякого значення, всі ці слова можна трактувати як окремі слова, хоч і з подібним значенням.
В українській мові слова *добавляти* (з якого й утворилося слово *добавка*) немає, це є калька з російської.
Як на мене, *просити прибавки* не ріже вухо аж так і цілком ок звучить, також не варто на силу намагатися знайти однослівний варіант, можна теж *просити додаткову порцію*, якщо сказати на 1 слово більше - язик не висохне.

Comment: Але є це цілком літературні слова **[вибавляти](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=7820&page=290)**, [набавляти](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=53174&page=1696), [надбавляти](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=54095&page=1722), **[позбавляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozbavljaty)**, [убавляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/ubavljaty).

Comment: @Sasha правда, але за змістом вони зовсім інші, деякі навіть протилежні, наприклад, `позбавляти`. А `надбавляти` з можна прирівняти до `надбавки`, різниця лише у частині мови, одне - дієслово, інше - іменник.

Comment: (Але корінь, на мою думку, той самий. (Зміст протилежний, бо префікс _з-_.))

Comment: @Sasha ну... вода і водій теж мають спільний корінь, але це ніяк не впливає на значення цих слів.

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, не мають. Вода і водій не однокорінні, лише схожі. Вода — від праіндоєвропейського [*wed-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/wed-), вести/водити/водій — від праіндоєвропейського [*wedʰ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/wedʰ-).

Comment: @Sasha можливо, я не філолог, намагаюся лише логічно все поєднати. бтв, [goroh](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) ніби подає в етимології можливі корені, [ось посилання на вікі](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/baviti), і там дійсно вказується, що baviti - може означати «накопичувати», «додавати», але тоді виникає питання, чому слова «добавити» немає в українській, а всі словники позначають його як розмовне, а не літературне?

Comment: як на мене, вживання слів добавити, прибавити не було досліджене свого часу і позначки, що ми бачимо в СУМ є дуже відносні. Якщо слова позбавляти або вибавляти є літературними із закладеним значенням - звільняти або забирати, то добавляти або прибавляти, з геть протилежним значенням спричиняють плутанину і віддають запозиченням.

Comment: @user3334216, на мою думку — бо не було потреби в цьому слові, бо українці вже вживали інше слово (або ж у певний момент часу слово стало менш популярним, бо його витіснило інше слово). Так трапляється, наприклад, ми зазвичай кажемо _дах_ замість _криша_. Але це не означає, що треба відмовляти в праві на існування спорідненим словам (наприклад, ми кажемо _крити_, _покрівля_, _покришка_ і навіть _кришка/кришечка_).